# jQuery Validate - step by step - hidden fieldset

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

Having a little bit of trouble with the following [page](http://jsfiddle.net/mynameisdonald/KB6wD/)

Ive made a 2 step process for a form where the first step is personal details in a fieldset and theres a next button which takes you to the second fieldset and hdies the first. and then theres a submit button which runs the jQuery Validation.

Only problem is that it seems to only validate the second fieldset even though I have specified all fields to be required.

Thanks

Comment: is the problem that they are not validating, or the "Required" label isn't being applied to the first fieldset? Also, it seems it would make sense to validate the first set before moving onto the next IMO

Comment: the first fieldset isnt validating, I have added the required fields into the Rules part of jQuery Validate.

Comment: What if you do a two step validation? On the first page, when clicking next validate and if it's succesful then go onto the second page and do the final validation when clicking submit.

Comment: Im trying to do this just now but the entire form is one page. Im using Fieldsets to show and hide each section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version [1.9.0 of jQuery Validate](http://bassistance.de/2011/10/07/release-validation-plugin-1-9-0/) added hidden fields (:hidden) to the ignore list by default; you can do the following to turn it back on:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    ignore: []
});
```

I hope this helps!